# Tabs in Jetpack Compose with HorizontalPager duplicate my information

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using a Google Accompanist HorizontalPager in my application so I can swipe with my finger to move between tabs.

It works fine, except that each tab is replicating the same information as the other. Each tab contains a fragment that is the same component with the same API call in which only one parameter changes.

There are 3 tabs, the one I load initially is number 1, that is to say the central one, and it loads fine, but when I change to 0 or 2, the information is replicated in all of them showing the same.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun Tabs(zodiacName: String?, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, pagerState: PagerState) {
    val viewModel = getViewModel<DetailViewModel>()
    val tabTitles = listOf("Yesterday", "Today", "Tomorrow")
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column(
        modifier
    ) {
        TabRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(
                        pagerState,
                        tabPositions
                    ),
                    height = 2.dp
                )
            }) {
            tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = {
                         coroutineScope.launch {
                             pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                         }
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = title,
                            color = Color.White,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            fontFamily = Helvetica
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(count = tabTitles.size, state = pagerState) { page ->
            when (page) {
                0 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "yesterday"
                )
                1 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "today"
                )
                2 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "tomorrow"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this would be the content of the component for the view in which only the field of the call that I pass through a parameter changes:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Prediction(viewModel: DetailViewModel, zodiacName: String?, day: String?) {
    val errorMessage = viewModel.errorMessage.value
    val horoscope = viewModel.horoscopeResponse.value
    if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 20.dp, bottom = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)
        ) {
            item {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    viewModel.getHoroscopeDetail(zodiacName, day)
                }
                if (horoscope.checkDescriptionContent()) {
                    PredictionCard(horoscope = horoscope)

                } else {
                    ShimmerCard()
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        ErrorComponent(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            sign = zodiacName,
            day = day
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried creating a different component for each tab, but it has not solved it. I would like to know why the information is being replicated in all of them and how to make each tab show the information that corresponds to it.

Comment: I already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71004023/3585796) why your solution is wrong. It's hard to help you without [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and simply displaying `Text` instead of `Prediction` works fine, [here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/c44269cbe9586f53afecf301b7592ab1) is the code I tried.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer myself, the problem is that I was taking the page returned by the HorizontalPager instead of the one from the PagerState. The solution would be:

```kotlin
HorizontalPager(count = tabTitles.size, state = pagerState) {
            when (pagerState.currentPage) {
                0 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "yesterday"
                )
                1 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "today"
                )
                2 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "tomorrow"
                )
            }
        }
```