# Why in HorizontalPager is the page number returned by the lambda different from the currentPage?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using this component and I was having a problem, as I don't get the same result like this:

```kotlin
HorizontalPager(count = tabTitles.size, state = pageState) { page ->
     Log.i("Polaris", "Hi, I'm page $page")
     Log.i("Polaris", "Hi, I'm currentPage $currentPage")
}
```

The result I get is:

```
2022-02-05 17:16:06.461 31070-31070/com.polaris I/Polaris: Hi, I'm page 0
2022-02-05 17:16:06.461 31070-31070/com.polaris I/Polaris: Hi, I'm currentPage 0
2022-02-05 17:16:06.464 31070-31070/com.polaris I/Polaris: Hi, I'm page 1
2022-02-05 17:16:06.464 31070-31070/com.polaris I/Polaris: Hi, I'm currentPage 0
```

Why does currentPage always return me the current page I'm on and page returns me the current and next page?

**I edit the publication** to add the rest of the code. The problem is that given the result that the page parameter gives me, the call that I have inside the Prediction component, when going from one page to another, replicates the same information that I get from the service in each one, instead of putting the one that corresponds to each one:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun Tabs(zodiacName: String?, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val viewModel = getViewModel<DetailViewModel>()
    val tabTitles = listOf("Yesterday", "Today", "Tomorrow")
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val pageState = rememberPagerState()
    Column(
        modifier
    ) {
        TabRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            selectedTabIndex = pageState.currentPage,
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(
                        pageState,
                        tabPositions
                    ),
                    height = 2.dp
                )
            }) {
            tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(selected = pageState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            pageState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = title,
                            color = Color.White,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            fontFamily = Helvetica
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(count = tabTitles.size, state = pageState) {
            when (currentPage) {
                0 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "yesterday"
                )
                1 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "today"
                )
                2 -> Prediction(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    zodiacName = zodiacName,
                    day = "tomorrow"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The content of the Prediction component is as follows:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Prediction(viewModel: DetailViewModel, zodiacName: String?, day: String?) {
    val errorMessage = viewModel.errorMessage.value
    val horoscope = viewModel.horoscopeResponse.value
    if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 20.dp, bottom = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)
        ) {
            item {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    viewModel.getHoroscopeDetail(zodiacName, day)
                }
                if (horoscope.checkDescriptionContent()) {
                    PredictionCard(horoscope = horoscope)

                } else {
                    ShimmerCard()
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        ErrorComponent(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            sign = zodiacName,
            day = day
        )
    }
}
```

Why then if I use currentPage it works fine, it makes the calls and places all the information correctly, but if I use the page parameter contained in the lambda, it duplicates the information?

Comment: Page is a lambda parameter of the last argument of `HorizontalPage`, but what I don't understand is where the variable "currentPage" is coming from. If "currentPage" is a remember variable inside your compose function, then this could be causing this effect. Can you provide the rest of the code please?

Comment: @PierreVieira I have edited my complete code and explained the behaviour I get.

Answer (score 3):

The `HorizontalPager` pre-draws a pair of adjacent pages, so that when you start scrolling, you don't have to wait for rendering.

This is exactly what happens in your logs: `content` is called for the first page and for the second, but `currentPage` is `0` in both cases.

You must always use the `page` parameter when creating a view within `content`, otherwise the view will be built on the wrong value during scrolling. When scrolling is over, the view will be recomposed with the new `currentPage` value, so it may look fine when scrolling fast, but if you scroll slowly, you will se the problem.

You can easily see how this works in the following example. See how I first scroll through the page without releasing my finger and `currentPage` shows the "wrong" number, which is updated when I release my finger and the animation ends.

```
HorizontalPager(
    count = 10,
) { page ->
    Column {
        Text("page $page")
        Text("currentPage $currentPage")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to make it slow and fast and the only behaviour is that it does not load the corresponding information until I am inside the tab, but it does not duplicate the information as it happens in the case of using the lambda parameter.

Comment: @Ludiras I'm not sure I understand you, but I tried to add an example that should make more sense. If that didn't help, please explain what you mean by "duplicate the information"?

Comment: @Felipe Dujov Nothing, the problem is not with your example or the HorizontalPager. It's my code. I thought that when I turn the page, the information of the previous page is kept, but no, the call of the viewModel is launched again, and what it does is to keep what it contains the last time the viewModel is called, that's why the first time I open the screen it comes out fine, but when I turn the tab, the call corresponding to that tab is made and it paints in that tab and smashes in the previous one.

Comment: @Ludiras after your edit your question duplicated your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997688/tabs-in-jetpack-compose-with-horizontalpager-duplicate-my-information). I think my answer is a good explanation of your original question, and as to your previous question - there isn't much I can help you here without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try to remove as much unrelated code as possible - for example, `ErrorComponent` should have nothing to do with the problem. And update your code so that it can be run in a sample project without any changes - many classes/functions are missing there now. Focus more on removing unnecessary code rather than adding missing code - that way you might be able to find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should review the documentation on how to get your page index current.
[enter link description here](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    // Collect from the pager state a snapshotFlow reading the currentPage
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
        Log.d("abc","currentPage : $page")
    }
}
```